# Zend Framework: How can I tap into the final view output before it's sent to the browser?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, rendering

I'm trying to access the final xhtml output right before it's sent to the browser as a string. The postDispatch() methods of the actions and plugins seem to be too early to do this. When I step through `Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch()` method using a debugger, I can access the desired output as a string right before `$this->_response->sendResponse()` is called at the very end by adding a watch expression `$this->getResponse()->getBody()`. However, there seems to be no dedicated hook to tap into right there. I need the final response body as a string in order to send it to Prince XML to generate a pdf. Does anybody know an elegant way to do this?

Thanks, Adrian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Zend_Controller_Front` plugin hooks are the following (from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)):

- `routeStartup()` is called before `Zend_Controller_Front` calls on the router to evaluate the request against the registered routes.
- `routeShutdown()` is called after the router finishes routing the request.
- `dispatchLoopStartup()` is called before `Zend_Controller_Front` enters its dispatch loop.
- `preDispatch()` is called before an action is dispatched by the dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior. By altering the request and resetting its dispatched flag (via `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract::setDispatched(false)`), the current action may be skipped and/or replaced.
- `postDispatch()` is called after an action is dispatched by the dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior. By altering the request and resetting its dispatched flag (via `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract::setDispatched(false)`), a new action may be specified for dispatching.
- **`dispatchLoopShutdown()` is called after Zend_Controller_Front exits its dispatch loop.**

So `dispatchLoopShutdown()` is your hook to go - it's the last thing `Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch()` does before returning or sending the response.

Another option could be, even though they were designed for something completely different, to use `Zend_View` filters. These filters can be added to the `Zend_View`-instance and are called in `Zend_View::render()`. A filter is simply an instance of a class that provides a `filter($buffer)`-method that returns the filtered `$buffer`. But using this interface for something not related to *filtering* the ouptut, seems not to be the correct way actually.

I personally think, that a `dispatchLoopShutdown()`-plugin will be the way to go.

Comment: That was the perfect answer, thank you so much! I bow to the infinite wisdom of SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample on how to use view filters

http://matthewturland.com/2008/06/04/output-filters-in-zend_view/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.